# Algorithm for determining all the zeros of a complex rational function without initial guesses

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, roots, rational-functions

Given a rational function R(x) = P(x)/Q(x), where P and Q are polynomials which can have complex coefficients, is there an algorithm which allows us to determine the zeros of R without an initial guess of the values of the zeros?

There are methods to determine approximate values of all the roots of P without any initial guesses. For example by computing the eigenvalues of the companion matrix (see [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html)). Among these roots are all the zeros of R. The problem is that some roots may not be zeros of R, if they are a root of Q with at least the same multiplicity as P. I'm really looking for a robust way of checking that.

Comment: A zero of $R$ must be a zero of $P$. So any polynomial algorithm would work.

Comment: But a zero of P (let's call it x) is not necessarily a zero of  R. You could think that all we need to do is to check if R(x)=0, but numerically you will always get some finite value for R(x), and it is then difficult to assert if x is truly a zero of R.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce $P(x)/Q(x)$ to lowest terms by using the Euclidean algorithm to find $\gcd(P(x),Q(x))$. Then the zeros  of $R$ are exactly the zeros of the numerator.